# Disable auto-refresh file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a issue related with the files opened in my Visual Studio Code.

In my team we can edit the same file (shared in the intranet) and I want to know when the file was updated.

Exist a way to detect this in Visual Studio Code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shyykoserhiy.sockscode-vscode?

Comment: @wlisrausr This isn't what I want :( . If you're working with notepad++ and a file is changed, in the np++ a message is prompt informing the update and ask you if want to reload the file. I want this same behavior in the VSC

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be added in some day, look here and vote if you want it to be add: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23107